# Ruby - Does array A contain all elements of array B

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Is there any method to check if array A contains all the elements of array B?

Comment: Show an example of arrays you want to compare. Do you mean that Array A can contain the same elements with the same number of elements, or just the same elements and different count of them

Comment: Do you care about repetition? For example, let a be [1,2,3,4] and b be [1,1,2]. What should the return value be?

Comment: Ruby's introduced `difference` in 2.6 which provides a perfect fast and readable solution for this. [More info here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890717/ruby-does-array-a-contain-all-elements-of-array-b/56739686#answer-56739686)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work for what you need:

```
(a & b) == b
```

Comment: this won't work as a rule. `a = [1,2,2,1,3]; b = [3,2,1]; (a & b) == b => false`

Comment: Yes, but `a = [1,2,2,1,3]; b = [3,2,1]; (a & b).sort == b.sort 
=> true`

Comment: @the Tin Man, Yes, but a = [1,2,2,1,3]; b = [3,2,2,1]; (a & b).sort == b.sort => false

Comment: no need to sort just reverse the order of the binary AND

Answer (score 19):

You can try this

```
a.sort.uniq == b.sort.uniq
```

or

```
(a-b).empty?
```

And if `[1,2,2] != [1,2]` in your case you can:

```
a.group_by{|i| i} == b.group_by{|i| i}
```

Comment: +1 for `(a-b).empty?`

Comment: Just in case someone ends up here: **these are all wrong**. The correct answer is `(b-a).empty?`, not the other way around. Others are just plain wrong. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387937/ruby-rails-how-to-determine-if-one-array-contains-all-elements-of-another-array

Comment: @oseiskar no, they are not wrong. It depends on the task.

Comment: I don't think so. If the task is to answer the question _does array A contain all elements of array B_, which quite literally translates to Ruby as `B.map{|e|A.include?(e)}.all?`, then none of these give the correct answer in the generic case (or, e.g., the first example I came up with: A = [1,2,3], B = [1,2]).

Comment: @oseiskar yes, this sounds reasonable. In generic case they all wrong.

Comment: Wow, they really are all wrong!  You cannot call `sort` on every Arrays (e.g. `[1,'a']`, and it should be `(b-a).empty?`.

Answer (score 7):

You could use Ruby's `Set` class:

```
>> require 'set' #=> true
>> a = [*1..5] #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>> b = [*1..3] #=> [1, 2, 3]
>> a.to_set.superset? b.to_set #=> true
```

For small arrays I usually do the same as what fl00r suggested:

```
>> (b-a).empty? #=> true
```

Answer (score 6):

I prefer to do this via: `(b - a).blank?` # tells that b is contained in a

Comment: it's more elegant Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is this:

```
(b-a).empty?
```

Answer (score 3):

There's also the Set class (part of the standard library) which would allow you to just check to see if B is a subset of A, e.g.

```
>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]       => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>> b = [3,4,5]           => [3, 4, 5]
>> require 'set'         => true 
>> set_a = a.to_set      => #<Set: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}> 
>> set_b = b.to_set      => #<Set: {3, 4, 5}> 

>> set_b.subset? set_a   => true
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/index.html

Answer (score 3):

**Ruby 2.6+**

Ruby's introduced [`difference`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Array.html#method-i-difference) in 2.6 for exactly this purpose.

Very fast, very readable, as follows:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

a.difference(b).any?
# => false
a.difference(b.reverse).any?
# => false

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [1, 2, 3]
a.difference(b).any?
# => true
```

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the [Set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/classes/Set.html) class in the Ruby Standard library. The [`proper_subset?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/classes/Set.html#M003474) method will probably do what you want.