# How to determine if one array contains all elements of another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Given:

```
a1 = [5, 1, 6, 14, 2, 8]
```

I would like to determine if it contains all elements of:

```
a2 = [2, 6, 15]
```

In this case the result is `false`.

Are there any built-in Ruby/Rails methods to identify such array inclusion?

One way to implement this is:

```
a2.index{ |x| !a1.include?(x) }.nil?
```

Is there a better, more readable, way?

Comment: The accepted answer (array subtraction) is the fastest solution. I benchmarked all of them here: https://gist.github.com/bbugh/cbbde8b48cbb16286044f6893e1f2e5f

Answer (score 379, accepted):

```
a = [5, 1, 6, 14, 2, 8]
b = [2, 6, 15]

a - b
# => [5, 1, 14, 8]

b - a
# => [15]

(b - a).empty?
# => false
```

Comment: This the the way to go. It might just be a bit shortened to `(a2-a1).empty?`

Comment: This only works for arrays that are sets, not for arrays with duplicates

Comment: @Chris - You could try using Array#uniq for that. With Holger Just's example, it would be `(a2.uniq - a1.uniq).empty?`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553822/determine-if-one-array-contains-all-elements-of-another-array is what I meant. Array#unique will explicitly fail that.

Comment: Great answers and the suggestions in the comments, they were all really helpfull!

Answer (score 95):

Perhaps this is easier to read:

```
a2.all? { |e| a1.include?(e) }
```

You can also use array intersection:

```
(a1 & a2).size == a1.size
```

Note that `size` is used here just for speed, you can also do (slower):

```
(a1 & a2) == a1
```

But I guess the first is more readable. These 3 are plain ruby (not rails).

Comment: If using the OP's definition of a1 and a2, and a1 "containing all elements of" a2, I think this should be _ (a1 & a2).size == a2.size _ since a2 is the smaller array, which should have all elements included in the larger array (to obtain 'true') - hence the intersection of the two arrays should be the same length as the smaller-array if all elements in it are present in the larger one.

Comment: By the way, Ruby 2.7 introduced a new `intersection` method so we can use a more readable approach right now `(a1.intersection(a2)).size == a1.size`

Answer (score 64):

This can be achieved by doing

```
(a2 & a1) == a2
```

This creates the intersection of both arrays, returning all elements from `a2` which are also in `a1`. If the result is the same as `a2`, you can be sure you have all elements included in `a1`.

This approach only works if all elements in `a2` are different from each other in the first place. If there are doubles, this approach fails. The one from Tempos still works then, so I wholeheartedly recommend his approach (also it's probably faster).

Comment: using the `length` method will perform much better

Comment: This won't work if the intersection set has the same elements in a different order. I found this out the hard way while trying to answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062970/array-permutations-and-comparisons-does-this-array-contain-any-of-these-arrays/12077841#12077841 later realized many smart folks had done it here already!

Comment: @CubaLibre Interesting. Do you have some test data to reproduce this? Fom my tests it seemed as if the resulting array retains the order of elements from the first array (hence my most recent edit to my answer). However, if this is indeed not the case, I'd like to learn.

Comment: @HolgerJust i had made the mistake of doing (a1 & a2) instead of (a2 & a1), which is why I was seeing the error. You are right about & retaining the order from the first array.

Comment: From my limited testing it appears that order no longer matters.

Answer (score 13):

If there are are no duplicate elements or you don't care about them, then you can use the [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/index.html) class:

```
a1 = Set.new [5, 1, 6, 14, 2, 8]
a2 = Set.new [2, 6, 15]
a1.subset?(a2)
=> false
```

Behind the scenes this uses

```
all? { |o| set.include?(o) }
```

Comment: I like it. In a single line it would be `a1.to_set.subset?(a2.to_set)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can monkey-patch the Array class:

```
class Array
    def contains_all?(ary)
        ary.uniq.all? { |x| count(x) >= ary.count(x) }
    end
end
```

test

```
irb(main):131:0> %w[a b c c].contains_all? %w[a b c]
=> true
irb(main):132:0> %w[a b c c].contains_all? %w[a b c c]
=> true
irb(main):133:0> %w[a b c c].contains_all? %w[a b c c c]
=> false
irb(main):134:0> %w[a b c c].contains_all? %w[a]
=> true
irb(main):135:0> %w[a b c c].contains_all? %w[x]
=> false
irb(main):136:0> %w[a b c c].contains_all? %w[]
=> true
irb(main):137:0> %w[a b c d].contains_all? %w[d c h]
=> false
irb(main):138:0> %w[a b c d].contains_all? %w[d b c]
=> true
```

Of course the method can be written as a standard-alone method, eg

```
def contains_all?(a,b)
    b.uniq.all? { |x| a.count(x) >= b.count(x) }
end
```

and you can invoke it like

```
contains_all?(%w[a b c c], %w[c c c])
```

Indeed, after profiling, the following version is much faster, and the code is shorter.

```
def contains_all?(a,b)
    b.all? { |x| a.count(x) >= b.count(x) }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Most answers based on (a1 - a2) or (a1 & a2) would not work if there are duplicate elements in either array. I arrived here looking for a way to see if all letters of a word (split to an array) were part of a set of letters (for scrabble for example). None of these answers worked, but this one does:

```
def contains_all?(a1, a2)
  try = a1.chars.all? do |letter|
    a1.count(letter) <= a2.count(letter)
  end
  return try
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how big your arrays are you might consider an efficient algorithm O(n log n)

```
def equal_a(a1, a2)
  a1sorted = a1.sort
  a2sorted = a2.sort
  return false if a1.length != a2.length
  0.upto(a1.length - 1) do 
    |i| return false if a1sorted[i] != a2sorted[i]
  end
end
```

Sorting costs O(n log n) and checking each pair costs O(n) thus this algorithm is O(n log n). The other algorithms cannot be faster (asymptotically) using unsorted arrays.

Comment: You can do it in O(n) with a counting sort.

Comment: No you cannot. Counting sort uses a limited universe and Ruby does not have a limitation on how big numbers can get.

Comment: You can, because you don't actually have to sort the items - you just need a hash mapping item-->count for both arrays, then iterate over the keys and compare counts.

Comment: Are you sure that Array#sort uses merge sort?

Answer (score 0):

I was directed to this post when trying to find whether one array `["a", "b", "c"]` contained another array `["a", "b"]`, where in my case **identical ordering** was an additional requirement to the question.

Here is my solution (I believe it's O(n) complexity), to anyone who has that extra requirement:

```rb
def array_includes_array(array_to_inspect, array_to_search_for)
  inspectLength = array_to_inspect.length
  searchLength = array_to_search_for.length

  if searchLength == 0 then
    return true
  end

  if searchLength > inspectLength then
    return false
  end

  buffer = []

  for i in 0..inspectLength
    buffer.push(array_to_inspect[i])

    bufferLastIndex = buffer.length - 1
    if(buffer[bufferLastIndex] != array_to_search_for[bufferLastIndex]) then
      buffer.clear
      next
    end

    if(buffer.length == searchLength) then
      return true
    end
  end

  return false
end
```

This produces the test results:

```rb
puts "1: #{array_includes_array(["a", "b", "c"], ["b", "c"])}" # true
puts "2: #{array_includes_array(["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b"])}" # true
puts "3: #{array_includes_array(["a", "b", "c"], ["b", "b"])}" # false
puts "4: #{array_includes_array(["a", "b", "c"], ["c", "b", "a"])}" # false
puts "5: #{array_includes_array(["a", "b", "c"], [])}" # true
puts "6: #{array_includes_array([], ["a"])}" # false
puts "7: #{array_includes_array([], [])}" # true
```