# Array permutations and comparisons: Does this array contain any of these arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays, permutation

I've looked all over SO for an answer to this, and while I've found a few similar problems, I just haven't been able to solve my problem.

I'm building a Mastermind game. Right now I'm working on the algorithm for an intelligent computer guess. I've read about this a lot, but as someone fairly new to programming, it's been a bit of a challenge to develop this algorithm (I'm using TDD).

```
secret_code = %w(blue blue orange orange)
guess = %w(orange blue red yellow)
valid_colors = %w(blue green orange purple red yellow)
possible_secret_codes = valid_colors.repeated_permutation(4).to_a
```

I want to eliminate as many possible_secret_codes as I can based on the feedback (the score) I receive after making my guess.

One potential approach (simple, albeit not the most efficient) is to first focus on finding the correct four colors, regardless of location.

```
score = {exact: 1, close: 1}
total_score = score[:exact] + score[:close]
parts_of_secret_code = guess.repeated_permutation(total_score).to_a.uniq
```

parts_of_secret_code is going to return an array of arrays. We can be certain that the secret code includes *AT LEAST ONE* of those arrays. I want to eliminate from the possible_secret_codes any code that does not include at least one of those arrays.

Using the example information I provided (assuming the secret code I provided, the guess I provided, the score I provided, etc.), this is what parts_of_secret_code would be:

```
parts_of_secret_code = [["orange", "orange"],
                        ["orange", "blue"],
                        ["orange", "red"],
                        ["orange", "yellow"],
                        ["blue", "orange"],
                        ["blue", "blue"],
                        ["blue", "red"],
                        ["blue", "yellow"],
                        ["red", "orange"],
                        ["red", "blue"],
                        ["red", "red"],
                        ["red", "yellow"],
                        ["yellow", "orange"],
                        ["yellow", "blue"],
                        ["yellow", "red"],
                        ["yellow", "yellow"]]
```

I want to eliminate codes that do not have at least one of those arrays. Doing this will cut down the original list of possible_secret_codes (1,296 total) that is found by calling repeated_permutation on the array of valid colors (as I showed above):

```
possible_secret_codes = valid_colors.repeated_permutation(4).to_a
```

Can anyone think of a way to do that?  I've tried a bunch of things and haven't been able to figure it out.

Thanks in advance for the help and let me know if I didn't provide enough information!  (And I know that title might be odd...wasn't sure how to word it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I want to eliminate codes that do not have at least one of those arrays."

```
require 'set' 
possible_secret_codes.select do |ary|
  parts_of_secret_codes.any? {|part| part.to_set.subset? ary.to_set}
end
```

What the code snippet does is to `select` those arrays from `possible_secret_codes` that satisfy the condition

```
parts_of_secret_codes.any? {|part| part.to_set.subset? ary.to_set}
```

The condition expresses the fact that `part` is a proper subset of `ary`.

Comment: That doesn't quite work.  For example, say `possible_secret_codes` is:  
`[%w(blue red orange orange), %w(red orange blue yellow), %w(yellow purple yellow yellow)]`  

And parts_of_secret_codes is:  
`[%w(orange red), %w(blue yellow), %w(purple orange)]`  

Your code *should* select (or keep) two of the `possible_secret_codes`, `%w(blue red orange orange)` and `%w(red orange blue yellow)`  

What it does in reality, however, is only keep this:  
`%w(red orange blue yellow)`  

It incorrectly rejects `%w(blue red orange orange)`  
*Note: I can't get line breaks to work.

Comment: Updated my answer to use the `Set` class available in Ruby std-lib. I was trying to mimic the subset? behavior using (ary & part) == part, but it wouldn't work if the intersection set had elements in the wrong order. HTH.

Comment: This question might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387937/ruby-rails-how-to-determine-if-one-array-contains-all-elements-of-another-array

Comment: Ah, okay. I also just discovered 'set' a few hours ago. I wasn't able to figure out a way to do it without requiring 'set'.

Comment: The previous solution would've worked if I wrote `(part & ary) == part` as against `(ary & part) == part`

The `Array#&` method retains the order of elements from its receiver in the result.