# Determine if one array contains all elements of another array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I need to tell if an array contains all of the elements of another array *with duplicates*.

```
[1,2,3].contains_all? [1,2]   #=> true
[1,2,3].contains_all? [1,2,2] #=> false (this is where (a1-a2).empty? fails)
[2,1,2,3].contains_all? [1,2,2] #=> true
```

So the first array must contain as many or equal of the number of each unique element in the second array.

[This question answers it for those using an array as a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387937/ruby-rails-how-to-determine-if-one-array-contains-all-elements-of-another-array), but I need to control for duplicates.

### Update: Benchmarks

On Ruby 1.9.3p194

```
def bench
  puts Benchmark.measure {
    10000.times do
      [1,2,3].contains_all? [1,2]
      [1,2,3].contains_all? [1,2,2]
      [2,1,2,3].contains_all? [1,2,2]
    end
  }
end
```

Results in:

```
Rohit   0.100000   0.000000   0.100000 (  0.104486)
Chris   0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.040178)
Sergio  0.160000   0.020000   0.180000 (  0.173940)
sawa    0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.032393)
```

### Update 2: Larger Arrays

```
@a1 = (1..10000).to_a
@a2 = (1..1000).to_a
@a3 = (1..2000).to_a

def bench
  puts Benchmark.measure {
    1000.times do
      @a1.contains_all? @a2
      @a1.contains_all? @a3
      @a3.contains_all? @a2
    end
  }
end
```

Results in:

```
Rohit    9.750000   0.410000  10.160000 ( 10.158182)
Chris   10.250000   0.180000  10.430000 ( 10.433797)
Sergio  14.570000   0.070000  14.640000 ( 14.637870)
sawa     3.460000   0.020000   3.480000 (  3.475513)
```

Comment: You should benchmark for much bigger arrays. (Unless its always going to be small for your use-case)

Comment: looks like @sawa's answer definitely wins for huge arrays, but I'm never going to have arrays that large. Regardless, sawa's implementation seems to be the best so far

Comment: If you flip it, like `@a2.contains_all? @a1`, the hash based answers will be faster. Though for small arrays, it really doesn't matter which way you go.

Comment: You would probably add a check to make sure the other array is smaller (impossible to return true) so that scenario would be constant time for all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Array
  def contains_all? other
    other = other.dup
    each{|e| if i = other.index(e) then other.delete_at(i) end}
    other.empty?
  end
end
```

Comment: nice! Seems like the best so far

Answer (score 2):

Here's a naive and straightforward implementation (not the most efficient one, likely). Just count the elements and compare both elements and their occurrence counts.

```
class Array
  def contains_all? ary
    # group the arrays, so that 
    #   [2, 1, 1, 3] becomes {1 => 2, 2 => 1, 3 => 1}
    my_groups = group_and_count self
    their_groups = group_and_count ary

    their_groups.each do |el, cnt|
      if !my_groups[el] || my_groups[el] < cnt
        return false
      end
    end

    true
  end

  private
  def group_and_count ary
    ary.reduce({}) do |memo, el|
      memo[el] ||= 0
      memo[el] += 1
      memo
    end
  end

end

[1, 2, 3].contains_all? [1, 2]   # => true
[1, 2, 3].contains_all? [1, 2, 2] # => false
[2, 1, 2, 3].contains_all? [1, 2, 2] # => true
[1, 2, 3].contains_all? [] # => true
[].contains_all? [1, 2] # => false
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need a multiset. Check out [this gem](https://github.com/maraigue/multiset), I think it does what you need.

You can use is and do something like (if the intersection is equal to the second multiset then the first one includes all of its elements):

```
@ms1 & @ms2 == @ms2
```

Answer (score 1):

Counting the number of occurrences and comparing them seems to be the obvious way to go.

```
class Array
   def contains_all? arr
       h = self.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|h, i| h[i] += 1; h}
       arr.each do |i|
           return false unless h.has_key?(i)
           return false if h[i] == 0
           h[i] -= 1
       end
       true
   end
end
```

Comment: If you are caring about speed, changing `== 0` to `zero?` will slightly improve the speed.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Array
  def contains_all?(ary)
    ary.uniq.all? { |x| count(x) >= ary.count(x) }
  end
end
```

test

```
irb(main):131:0> %w[a b c c].contains_all? %w[a b c]
=> true
irb(main):132:0> %w[a b c c].contains_all? %w[a b c c]
=> true
irb(main):133:0> %w[a b c c].contains_all? %w[a b c c c]
=> false
irb(main):134:0> %w[a b c c].contains_all? %w[a]
=> true
irb(main):135:0> %w[a b c c].contains_all? %w[x]
=> false
irb(main):136:0> %w[a b c c].contains_all? %w[]
=> true
```

The following version is faster and shorter in code.

```
class Array
  def contains_all?(ary)
    ary.all? { |x| count(x) >= ary.count(x) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering with my own implementation, but definitely want to see if someone can come up with a more efficient way. (I won't accept my own answer)

```
class Array
  def contains_all?(a2)
    a2.inject(self.dup) do |copy, el|
      if copy.include? el
        index = copy.index el
        copy.delete_at index
      else
        return false
      end
      copy
    end
    true
  end
end
```

And the tests:

```
1.9.3p194 :016 > [1,2,3].contains_all? [1,2]   #=> true
 => true 
1.9.3p194 :017 > [1,2,3].contains_all? [1,2,2] #=> false (this is where (a1-a2).empty? fails)
 => false 
1.9.3p194 :018 > [2,1,2,3].contains_all? [1,2,2] #=> true
 => true
```

Comment: AFAIK `Array#index` and `Array#include?` are `O(n)`. The array is iterated for each call. So if you have large arrays, that could pose a problem. And you can break out of the loop when `contains = false`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will only iterate through both lists once, and hence run in linear time. It might however be too much overhead if the lists are expected to be very small.

```
  class Array
    def contains_all?(other)
      return false if other.size > size
      elem_counts = other.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |elem,hash| hash[elem] += 1 }
      each do |elem|
        elem_counts.delete(elem) if (elem_counts[elem] -= 1) <= 0
        return true if elem_counts.empty?
      end
      false
    end
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

If you can't find a method, you can build one using ruby's *include?* method.

Official documentation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F

Usage:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
array.include? 3       #=> true
```

Then, you can do a loop:

```
def array_includes_all?( array, comparision_array )
  contains = true
  for i in comparision_array do
    unless array.include? i
      contains = false
    end
  end
  return contains
end

array_includes_all?( [1,2,3,2], [1,2,2] )    #=> true
```

Comment: but array_includes_all?( [1,2,3], [1,2,2,2] ) will also be true because include?(2) will keep finding the same 2

Comment: Your code fails on OP's second example. It returns true, when it should return false.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I misunderstood the question.