# Rails Checking if One Array is in Another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have five models: Course, Lesson, Question, Answer and User.

What I'm trying to do is determine if the User has Answers for all of the Questions in a Lesson (so I can put "Done" next to the lesson in the view if this is the case).

My models:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lessons, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :questions, :through => :lessons
  has_many :users, through: :purchases
end

class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :answers, through: :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lesson
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  has_one :author
  has_many :courses, through: :purchases
end
```

What I tried to do was to check if a Lesson's Questions were in the Questions the User Answered, but the `includes?` line doesn't seem to be working the way I want.

in my controller, I have:

```
@lessons = @course.lessons
@answers = current_user.answers
@questions = Question.where(:id => @answers.map(&:question_id))
```

in my view, I have:

```
<% @lessons.each do |lesson| %>
  <% lesson_questions = lesson.questions %>
  <%= user_questions = @questions.where("lesson_id = ?", lesson.id)%>

  <% if user_questions.include?(lesson_questions)%>
    Done!      
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm not sure if this is the cause, but I noticed the lesson_questions are `#<Question::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x9c49698>`

While the user_questions are: `#<Question::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x9c48330>`

I'm wondering, (a) how I accomplish my objective of finding the Lessons with all of the Questions answered, and (b) if there's a more efficient way to do this.  Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby/Rails: How to determine if one array contains all elements of another array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387937/ruby-rails-how-to-determine-if-one-array-contains-all-elements-of-another-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem

You can't check if an array includes another array just like this:

```
user_questions.include?(lesson_questions)
```

You need to check if each element from `lesson_questions` is included in the `user_questions`.

Try these instead:

#### Solution: 1

```
lesson_questions.all? { |lq| user_questions.include?(lq) }
```

This should return true if all the `lesson_questions` are included in the `user_questions`.

#### Solution: 2

```
(lesson_questions - user_questions).empty?
```