# Is there any way good way to check if an array is in an array?

Tags: ruby

I have arrays:

```
a = [1,3,4,5]
b = [1,2,3]
```

Is there any short way to check:

```
a.include? b
```

It should return `true` as `3` is there.

I can do:

```
b.each do |bb|
 puts true if a.include? bb
end
```

but this is not a good way for iterating over a big array to check it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby/Rails: How to determine if one array contains all elements of another array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387937/ruby-rails-how-to-determine-if-one-array-contains-all-elements-of-another-array)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the array difference is empty:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 3, 4, 5]

(a - b).empty? # false
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using [Enumerable.any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F)

```
[1, 3, 4, 5].any? { |i| [1, 2, 3].include? i }
```

Comment: This is the only answer that doesn't iterate over one or both arrays in their entirety. Since OP says they don't want to iterate over large arrays, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array intersection:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,4]
c = [5,6]
```

It gives following results:

```
   (a & b).any?
   # true
   (a & c).any?
   # false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Set.disjoint?`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-disjoint-3F):

```
require 'set'
Set[1, 2, 3].disjoint? Set[3, 4] # => false
Set[1, 2, 3].disjoint? Set[4, 5] # => true
```

Answer (score 0):

If I subtract a - b and a has some elements that b has too, then the new array of a - b has a smaller number of elements, because a - b returns all elements, which a has but b has not. I can check the result against the original size.

```
a = [1,3,4,5]
b = [1,2,3]
(a - b).size < a.size
# => true
```