# Ruby, remove super-arrays

Tags: ruby

If I have an array of arrays, `A`, and want to get rid of all arrays in `A` who also have a sub-array in `A`, how would I do that. In this context, `array_1` is a sub-array of `array_2` if `array_1 - array_2 = []`. In the case that multiple arrays are simply rearranged versions of the same elements, bonus points if you can get rid of all but one of them, but you can handle this however you want if it's easier.

In python, I could easily use comprehension, with `A` being a set of frozen sets :

```
A = {a for a in A if all(b-a for b in A-{a})}
```

Is there a simple way to write this in ruby? I don't care if the order of `A` or it's arrays are preserved at all. Also, in my program, none of the arrays have duplicate elements, if that makes things any easier/faster.

**Example**

```
A = [[1,6],[1,2],[2,4],[3,5],[1,3,6],[2,3,6]] 
# [1,6] is a subarray of [1,3,6], so [1,3,6] should be removed
remove_super_arrays(A) 
> A = [[1,6],[1,2],[2,4],[3,5],[2,3,6]] 

A = [[1,2,4],[2,3,4],[1,4,5],[2,6]]
# although there is overlap, there are no subarrays, so nothing should be removed
remove_super_arrays(A)
> A = [[1,2,4],[2,3,4],[1,4,5],[2,6]]

A = [[1],[2,1,3],[2,4],[1,4]]
# [1] is a subarray of [2,1,3] and [1,4]
remove_super_arrays(A)
> A = [[1],[2,4]]
```

Comment: What is the desired return value if `A = [[1,2], [2,1]]`? Is it necessary that the remaining elements of `A` be in the same order as in `A`?

Comment: No ordering matters, `A = [[1,2], [2,1]]` doesn't really matter for my purposes, it could throw an error and I wouldn't mind, but I've added how I'd prefer it work to my answer.

Comment: I don't know Python, but I suspect there is a small problem with your Python expression. Please see the method that uses `select` in the *Alternative calculation* section I added at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
def remove_super_arrays(arr)
  order = arr.each_with_index.to_a.to_h
  arr.sort_by(&:size).reject.with_index do |a,i|
    arr[0,i].any? { |aa| (aa.size < a.size) && (aa-a).empty? }
  end.sort_by { |a| order[a] }
end
```

**Examples**

```
remove_super_arrays([[1,6],[1,2],[2,4],[3,5],[1,3,6],[2,3,6]] ) 
  #=> [[1,6],[1,2],[2,4],[3,5],[2,3,6]]

remove_super_arrays([[1,2,4],[2,3,4],[1,4,5],[2,6]])
  #=> [[1,2,4],[2,3,4],[1,4,5],[2,6]]

remove_super_arrays([[1],[2,1,3],[2,4],[1,4]])
  #=> [[1],[2,4]]
```

**Explanation**

Consider the first example.

```
arr = [[1,6],[1,2],[2,4],[3,5],[1,3,6],[2,3,6]]
```

We first save the positions of the elements of `a`

```
order = arr.each_with_index.to_a.to_h # save original order
  #=> {[1, 6]=>0, [1, 2]=>1, [2, 4]=>2, [3, 5]=>3, [1, 3, 6]=>4, [2, 3, 6]=>5}
```

Then reject elements of `arr`:

```
b = arr.sort_by(&:size)
  #=> [[1, 6], [1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [2, 3, 6]]
c = b.reject.with_index do |a,i|
  arr[0,i].any? { |aa| (aa.size < a.size) && (aa-a).empty? }
end
  #=> [[1, 6], [1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 5], [2, 3, 6]]
```

Lastly, reorder `c` to correspond to the original ordering of the elements of `arr`.

```
c.sort_by { |a| order[a] }
  #=> [[1, 6], [1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 5], [2, 3, 6]]
```

which in this case happens to be the same order as the elements of `c`.

Let's look more carefully at the calculation of `c`:

```
enum1 = b.reject
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[1, 6], [1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 5], [1, 3, 6],
  #     [2, 3, 6]]:reject> 
enum2 = enum1.with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [[1, 6], [1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 5],
  #     [1, 3, 6], [2, 3, 6]]:reject>:with_index>
```

The first element is generated by the enumerator `enum2` and passed to the block and assigned as values of the block variables:

```
a, i = enum2.next
  #=> [[1, 6], 0] 
a #=> [1, 6] 
i #=> 0
```

The block calculation is then performed:

```
d = arr[0,i]
  #=> [] 
d.any? { |aa| (aa.size < a.size) && (aa-a).empty? }
  #=> false
```

so `a[0]` is not rejected. The next pair passed to the block by `enum2` is `[[1, 2], 1]`. That value is retained as well, but let's skip ahead to the last element passed to the block by `enum2`:

```
a, i = enum2.next
  #=> [[1, 2], 1] 
a, i = enum2.next
  #=> [[2, 4], 2] 
a, i = enum2.next
  #=> [[3, 5], 3]
```

```
a, i = enum2.next
  #=> [[1, 3, 6], 4] 
a #=> [1, 3, 6]
i #=> 4
```

Perform the block calculation:

```
d = arr[0,i]
  #=> [[1, 6], [1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 5]] 
d.any? { |aa| (aa.size < a.size) && (aa-a).empty? }
  #=> true
```

As `true` is returned, `a` is rejected. In the last calculation the first element of `d` is passed to the block and the following calculation is performed:

```
aa = [1, 6]
(aa.size < a.size)
  #=> 2 < 3 => true
(aa-a).empty?
  #=> ([1, 6] - [1, 3, 6]).empty? => [].empty? => true
```

As `true && true #=> true`, `a` (`[1, 3, 6]`) is rejected.

**Alternative calculation**

The following is a closer match to the OP's Python equivalent, but less efficient:

```
def remove_super_arrays(arr)
  arr.select do |a|
    (arr-[a]).all? { |aa| aa.size > a.size || (aa-a).any? }
  end
end
```

or

```
def remove_super_arrays(arr)
  arr.reject do |a|
    (arr-[a]).any? { |aa| (aa.size < a.size) && (aa-a).empty? }
  end
end
```

Comment: Great answer and explanation!

Comment: I’m sorry, does this change my inputted array or create a new one?

Comment: It returns a new array, leaving the original array unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

This was a nice exercise for me. I have used the logic from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387937/how-to-determine-if-one-array-contains-all-elements-of-another-array/7387998).

> My code iterates over each subarray (except the first), then there is the magic substraction using the first index, when it is empty the other array contained both numbers.

```
def remove_super_arrays(arr)
  arr.each_with_index.with_object([]) do |(sub_array, index), result|
    next if index == 0
    result << sub_array unless (arr.first - sub_array).empty?
  end.unshift(arr.first)
end
```

```
arr = [[1,6],[1,2],[2,4],[3,5],[1,3,6],[2,3,6]]   
p remove_super_arrays(arr)  
 #=> [[1, 6], [1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 5], [2, 3, 6]]
```

Comment: This is not order-preserving, one of the requirements: `remove_super_arrays [[1,2,4],[2,3,4],[1,4,5],[2,6]] #=> [[2, 6], [1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 5]]`. Compare this with the OP's second example.

Comment: You could of course do as I've done: save the ordering at the beginning then reorder at the end. Consider also `arr.each_with_index.with_object([]) do |(sub_array, index), result| ...` then `end.unshift(arr.first)` and delete `result = []`. There seems to be another problem: `remove_super_arrays [[2], [1], [1,3]]
 #=> [[2], [1], [1, 3]]`.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my answer with the `with_object part`. The rest remains as it is. I mean, it's not the accepted answer and was just an attempt to solve a challenge. Btw, nice email address trick in your profile :)