# Ruby rails include? array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to check inclusion array inside array?

i want to check if

`primary = [1,2,3]` includes `secondary = [2,3]`

i have tried `primary.include?(secondary) => false`

need to return bool value

Comment: not clear what you are asking

Comment: Are you searching for something similar to a subset or something similar to a substring?

Comment: this question has been asked several times

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890717/ruby-does-array-a-contain-all-elements-of-array-b

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387937/ruby-rails-how-to-determine-if-one-array-contains-all-elements-of-another-array

Comment: Do you want to check if elements **2,3** are present in primary or if **[2,3] array** is present inside primary array? The one which you have shown checks if **array [2,3]** is present inside **primary array** and as it is not present it returns false.

Comment: Could the arrays contain duplicates values? For example `primary = [1, 1, 2]` and `secondary = [1, 2, 2]`. If so, how would you define "inclusion" in that case?

Comment: The OP wants to know if the `secondary array` ( and not the elements of secondary array) is present in primary or not. The above case `secondary ([1,2,2])` is not present in the primary array so it would be false in that case.

Comment: @sahil How would you know that?

Comment: @Stefan Does this `Is it possible to check inclusion array inside array?` mean checking for the elements of `secondary` inside `primary`.

Comment: @sahil well, since `primary` only contains integers, it can't contain an array.

Comment: I'm taking it as `Can you find the elements of this other array in the same order in this original array?` So for `[1,2,3,4]` with test of `[2,3]` would be `true` but for `[1,3]` it would be false. But without feedback, we're all guessing here :)

Comment: @Stefan, I have upadted my answer for both cases now.

Comment: Should the sequence of items in secondary array matter in primary array or it should just find if all items of secondary array to be present in primary array?? Please clarify and update your post accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

## Solution

#### Without duplicates

If there aren't any duplicate, you can calculate the Array [difference](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-2D), and check if it is empty :

```
(secondary-primary).empty?
#=> true
```

#### General case

`subset_of?` checks that for every unique element in `secondary`, there are at least as many elements in `primary` :

```
class Array
  def count_by
    each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e, h| h[e] += 1 }
  end

  def subset_of?(superset)
    superset_counts = superset.count_by
    count_by.all? { |k, count| superset_counts[k] >= count }
  end
end
```

Example :

```
secondary.subset_of?(primary)
#=> true
[2,2].subset_of?([1, 2, 3])
#=> false
```

This should work for any Array, and it should be faster than other answers for big arrays.

## Test

```
([1,2,3] - [3,4,5,2,1]).empty?
#=> true
([1,2,3,'a'] - [3,4,5,2,1]).empty?
#=> false
```

Comment: It won’t work for duplicated entries: `[2, 2]` ∉ `[1, 2]`, while your solution gives `true`.

Comment: Shoot, you're right. Thanks.

Comment: The latter is a good one.

Answer (score 3):

```
test = primary.dup
secondary.all? { |e| test.index(e).tap { |i| test.delete_at(i) if i } }

primary, secondary = [1, 2, 3], [2, 2]
#⇒ false

primary, secondary = [1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 1]
#⇒ true
```

What’s being done here:

- we iterate `secondary`, claiming that all blocks should return `true`
- on each subsequent iteration we

  - immediately return `false` breaking the loop if there is no such element in `primary`
  - otherwise we mutate the copy of primary, removing the element already checked.

The only trick here is using [`Object#tap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-tap) to *always return `true` when element found*. The element in the `primary` might be `falsey`, `Array#delete` returns the element deleted and we might accidentally return `falsey`, mistakenly breaking a loop in such a case. We should return `true` to `all?` loop *as soon as we have the element found*, hence `tap`.

The input to verify that this is the only correct answer here so far:

```
primary, secondary = [1, 2, 2, 3, nil, nil], [2, 2, 1, nil, nil]
#⇒ true

primary, secondary = [1, 2, 2, 3, nil], [2, 2, 1, nil, nil]
#⇒ false
```

Comment: @Stefan good point, fixed.

Comment: @mudasobwa Can you please add little detail, like what `tap` will do here? And before this you assigned the `index` to `i` now you have created a `block` which will do similar thing. I am trying to understand the answer, but right now it is not clear to me.

Comment: @Deep please see an update.

Comment: This works for any arrays, but it can become very slow for large arrays. `primary = (1..100_000).to_a` and `secondary = primary.reverse` for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
primary = [1,2,3]
secondary = [2,3]
primary.each_cons(secondary.size).include?(secondary)
```

[Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) takes chunks of the array and iterates by one for each group.
Enumerable is awesome!

Read the [Enumerable docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html), I learn something new every time.

Comment: This only works for _consecutive_ elements. It won't work for `secondary = [1, 3]`

Comment: @Stefan I don't think that is what OP is asking. It sounds like they want the inclusion of the whole secondary array in the original. But you'd be right if that isn't what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [5, 1, 6, 14, 2, 8]
b = [2, 6, 15]

a - b
=> [5, 1, 14, 8]

b - a
=> [15]

#this is what you need
(b - a).empty?
=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if an array is present inside another array, just use the `include?` method,

```
primary = [1,2,3,[1,2]]
secondary = [2,3]

result = primary.include? secondary
# returns false as [2,3] is not present

primary = [1,2,3,[1,2]]
secondary = [1,2]
result = primary.include? secondary
# returns true as [1,2] is present
```

To check if the elements of secondary array are present inside the primary array, takes care of the duplicate elements also:

```
result = (secondary.select {|i| secondary.count(i)<=primary.count(i)}.length == secondary.length)

primary, secondary = [1, 2, 3], [2, 2]
# returns false

primary, secondary = [1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 1]
# returns true
```

Comment: Now the answer is sorta correct, but I am afraid to think how many iterations it requires on huge arrays.

Answer (score 0):

**Here solution**

```
primary=[1,2,3]  
secondary=[2,3]  
secondary.all? { |e| primary.include?(e) }
```

Comment: This is simply wrong. Try for `secondary = [2, 2]`.

Answer (score 0):

a1 = [5, 3, 9, 7, 8, 7, 1, 7]

a2 = [1, 9, 5, 7, 5]

It will check elements of `a2` are present in `a1` or not,

`a2.all?{ |i| a1.include? i }  #=> true`

Comment: It returns `true`, although `a1` only contains one `5`.

Answer (score -1):

Using

```
secondary.all? { |e| primary.include?(e) }
```

Use Intersection

```
(primary & secondary).size == secondary.uniq.size
```

If any element of secondary to be present in primary

```
(primary & secondary).present?
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong : `([1,7] & [2,7]).present? #=> true`

Comment: I thought any one element from secondary to be present in primary.

Comment: I think `inclusion` refers to `subset` : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset. I didn't downvote BTW.

Comment: DownVoter can you please remove it.

Comment: @GouravNaik I have it downvoted and I did it because this answer is wrong. Try `[1, 2, 2] & [2, 2]`.

Comment: @mudasobwa Okay, corrected it. Thank you for your answer

Comment: This is still wrong. Try `[1, 2] & [2, 2]`.

Comment: 2 is present in primary array, I guess OP did not mean exact same nested array to be present in primary. If he meant than yes my second solution is wrong.