# Why does is the index of the array repeatedly be printed out to be 2?

Tags: ruby

I'm working on this function:

It's supposed to take in an array and match it with a given word to see if that word can be formed with the given array of strings.

I added the two commented lines because I wanted to see how the for-loop works.

```
def canformword(arr,word)
  arrword = word.chars
  arrleft = arr
  flag = true
  for i in 0...arrword.size
    ch = arrword[i]
    # puts arrword[i]
    if !arrleft.include?(ch)
      flag = false
      break
    else
      ind = arrleft.index(ch)
      # puts ind
      arrleft.delete_at(ind)
    end
  end
  if flag
    puts 'can form word'
  else
    puts 'can not form word'
  end
end

canformword(['y','b','z','e','a','u','t'], 'beauty')
canformword(['r','o','u','g','h'], 'tough')
```

When I uncomment those two lines, the following is the output:

**Why does the output print out the index 2 repeatedly? I would think that it would print out the index of each letter in my arrleft array rather than repeatedly spitting out 2!**

I understand the 1 it prints out, because that's the index of b, but the rest is weird to me.

```
b
1
e
2
a
2
u
2
t
2
y
0
can form word
t
can not form word
```

Comment: One of the errors in your code is in `for i in 0...arrword.size`. You just can't go from `0` to `arrwords.size`. Assume your array has 5 elements. From `0` to `5` you would be counting **`6`** elements, see? It should be `for i in 0...arrword.size-1`.

Comment: Besides, do you really have to use a `for loop`? This could be made shorter using 'the Ruby way'.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for the insight. The reason I'm using the for-loop is because I just want to practice my Ruby. :)

Comment: You are welcome. Please also notice in the answer given by Nafaa Boutefer two important Ruby ways. **1)** Methods testing something and returning `true` or `false` are commonly named with a question mark (?) in the end. This makes things more readable, since such methods are really questions; **2)** Naming your method `can_form_word?` is better than `canformword?`. Also a matter of readability.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida `0...arrword.size` is correct (notice the three dots). Alternatively you can write `0..arrword.size-1`. OP: If you want to use a `for` loop you should be writing it as `for i in arrword`, then `i` is the element from the array. Anyway... you shouldn't be using `for` loops in the first place.

Comment: Then this restriction only applies if one loops using a range, @sagarpandya82? Like in `for i in (0..arrword.size-1)` or (0..arrword.size-1).each`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because you are deleting the character at position ind(arrleft.delete_at(ind)); so each time array characters are shifting one cell left.
Now as all your letters 'e','a','u','t','y' are placed ordered way so it is showing 2,2,2,2 continuously.
Now look at 'y'; it is at position 0 ; so 0 is printed at end.

So the issue is because you are deleting the characters at position 'ind'.

So, to achieve this you can just do one thing ; do not delete the characters when found rather replace it by some numeric value like '0'.

Answer (score 3):

hear a better implementation that

```
def can_form_word?(chars_array, word)
   (word.chars - chars_array).empty?
end
```

that's all.

here another implementation the Ruby way. Because your code is like `C`. I've been writing Ruby code for more than three years now, and I never used `for` loops.

```
def canformword(chars,word)
    word.each_char do |char|
       puts char
       if !chars.include?(char)
         return false # or puts "Can't form word"
       end
    end
    true # or puts "Can form word"
end
```

Comment: Do you assume that you can re-use the characters in the `chars_array` array?

Comment: And what happens to your code in this case the OP used to test: `canformword(['y','b','z','e','a','u','t'], 'beauty')`? It fails, because we have 'z' in `chars_array` which won't appear in `beauty` and then `(word.chars - chars_array).empty?` would be clearly `false` when the result should be true.

Comment: The OP never said that `chars_array` should contain ONLY the letter used in the word. It should return `true` if the given word may be formed by those letters.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida `'beauty'.chars - ['y','b','z','e','a','u','t']` returns `[]`

Comment: Really sorry. In fact.I thought about the opposite, `chars_array - word.chars`. I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida you can do it this way as well. `(word.chars | chars_array).size chars_array.uniq.size`, this means that the word chars didn't add any new chars to the array, which means the array can form the word.

Comment: I'd argue that the second method looks like C. You could just use `Enumerable#all?`.

Comment: Also, note that the method written in the question doesn't reuse characters since it deletes them one after the other. Your method wouldn't work for `['a', 'c', 'e', 'p', 't', 'b', 'l'], 'acceptable'`.

Answer (score 2):

You obtain 2 several times because you are deleting elements from the array. In that case you delete the second element every time so the next character, in the next iteration, take the index 2 again.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

If you want do delete index 2 and 3 from an array, you need to delete them in decreasing order, becausing deleting index 2 would modify index of 3:

```
array = %w(a b c d e)
array.delete_at(3)
array.delete_at(2)
p array
#=> ["a", "b", "e"]
```

or

```
array = %w(a b c d e)
array.delete_at(2)
array.delete_at(2)
p array
#=> ["a", "b", "e"]
```

## Solution

For your code, you just need to replace

```
arrleft.delete_at(ind)
```

with

```
arrleft[ind] = nil
```

## Alternative

Since you take the numbers of characters into account, here's a modified version of a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41482955/6419007) :

```
class Array
  def count_by
    each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e, h| h[e] += 1 }
  end

  def subset_of?(superset)
    superset_counts = superset.count_by
    count_by.all? { |k, count| superset_counts[k] >= count }
  end
end

def can_form_word?(chars, word)
  word.chars.subset_of?(chars)
end

p can_form_word?(['y','b','z','e','a','u','t'], 'beauty')
#=> true
p can_form_word?(['y','b','z','e','u','t'], 'beauty')
#=> false
p can_form_word?(['a', 'c', 'e', 'p', 't', 'b', 'l'], 'acceptable')
#=> false
p ('acceptable'.chars - ['a', 'c', 'e', 'p', 't', 'b', 'l']).empty?
#=> true
```